# Join Multiple Unique Keys into one

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench to create a `user` table. I would like to make `name` and `surname` unique. On their own, `name` or `surname` are not unique as long as both are not duplicated simultaneously by a separate record.

Can I do this using MySQL Workbench or do I have to execute a a SQL statement manually? If so, what is the syntax?

[image: user table]

So, there can be many `name=John` and `surname=Doe` but only 1 `John Doe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the tabs underneath the table design window, you'll see "Indexes". Click that tab, create a new unique index, tick the boxes for the columns you want to include in the unique index.

(The view you're looking at in your question is the "Columns" view, which lets you change details of individual columns, each of which can include a "unique" property, but for multi-column uniqueness you need to create an index.)